# performance of distributed tensorflow is bad and found high cpu-sys (long time wait on futex)

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

all,I am trying to run an NN model with distributed-tensorflow(2ps+2 worker,each on a standalone machine),the performance is bad,and worker's cpu-usage is between 50%~800% (machine has 40 cores)

1. I am pretty sure the input queue is ok(without starving problem).
2. I also have tried the "tcmlloc/lib/libtcmalloc.so",but no help
3. with profile tools "strace",I found something strange:long time wait on futex,sometimes even 2+ seconds wait on futex
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnFqj.jpg)
4. I also get the timeline info[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NNtQ.png)
5. however,When I run the same programe with no-distributed mode,I can achieved almost 4-5 times of performance compared with the distributed mode,and the cpu-usage almost 2000%~3000%
6. my code is:`    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device = "/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_id,cluster=cluster)):

   ```
   global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

   indexes, values, labels = inputs.inputs()
   logits = models.inference([indexes, values])
   with tf.name_scope('loss'):
       diff = labels * tf.log(logits)
       with tf.name_scope('total'):
           loss = -tf.reduce_mean(diff)

   tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
   with tf.name_scope('train'):
       print("learning_rate = %f" % FLAGS.learning_rate)
       #sync_opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate),
                                                 #replicas_to_aggregate=1, total_num_replicas=1, use_locking=False)
       sync_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
       train_step = sync_opt.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

   with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
       with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
           correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
       with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
           accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
   tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
   hooks = [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=6000)]
   sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)

   with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=if_chief,
                                           checkpoint_dir=None,
                                           hooks=hooks,config=sess_config,stop_grace_period_secs=20) as session:


       step = 0
       while not session.should_stop():
           start_time = time.time()

           run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
           _, global_step_value,loss_value = session.run([train_step, global_step,loss],options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
           run_metadata=run_metadata)
           if step > 0 and step % 1 == 0:

               duration = time.time() - start_time
               format_str = ("After %d traning steps (%d global steps), "
                             "loss on training batch is %3f. "
                             "(cost %d s)")
               print(format_str % (step, global_step_value, loss_value,duration))
           step += 1

           if step >0 and step % 10 == 0 :
                tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
                ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
                with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(ctf)`
   ```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: How did you find out that there was no starving in the input queue? Is the network latency high between ps and workers?

Comment: Thanks Fake！1、from the tensorboard，i can see the queue is full and dequeue-operation is fast 2、The latency is low,they are in a same IDC;3、I am suspecting the grpc performance:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6116 .However，it didn't published yet.   Any ideas?